# Handling outliers in the target variable

Tags: regression, svm, outliers

I'm using a support vector regression model. I know the target variable has some outliers and modeling the data directly leads to bad results (Rsquare close to 0.2). I'm pretty sure the outliers are affecting the way the SVR trains and impacts the cross validation score.

I have tried taking a log transformation of the target variable which seems to give better results, but still not very good (Rsquare = 0.4). I'm curious if anyone has encountered a similar problem and how you approached it? Any suggestions and/or alternate methods most welcome.